# s#arp lite: Weird "HasUniqueDomainSignature" validation error message

Tags: s#arp-architecture, s#arp

I have 2 tables, Stack and User, and its many to one.

```
           [HasUniqueDomainSignature(ErrorMessage = "This stack already exists")]
            public class Stack : Entity
            {
                [DomainSignature]
                public virtual string Title { get; set; }
                public virtual User PostBy { get; set; }
            }



            [HasUniqueDomainSignature(ErrorMessage="This email address already exists")]
            public class User : Entity
            {
                [DomainSignature]
                public virtual string Email { get; set; }

                public User()
                {
                    this.Stacks = new List<Stack>();
                }
            }
```

here's my code to add stack.  if I add a stack with unique title, everything works, no problem.  I add a new stack with title already exists in the databaes, validation failed,  I checked the ModelState, the validaiton faild because of User , not Stack object.  I am getting "This email address already exists",  I am not adding a new User, just assign the user to the Stack.  I should get "This stack already exists"

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Add(Stack stack)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = _userRepository.GetAll().Where(u => u.Email == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).SingleOrDefault();

            if (user == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("User cannot be found, please re-login.");

            stack.PostDate = DateTime.Now;
            stack.PostBy = user;

            ActionConfirmation<Stack> confirmation = _stackCudTasks.SaveOrUpdate(stack);

            if (confirmation.WasSuccessful)
            {
                TempData["message"] = confirmation.Message;
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag["message"] = confirmation.Message;
        }

        return View(_stackCudTasks.CreateEditViewModel(stack));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of things that caught my attention:

- Use the debugger during the post back.  What is "stack"'s User property?  Is it null or does it have a value?  If it has a value, is there a field in the view which is populating it with a value; e.g., ?  (If it's null, I'm wondering why the validation of User is being tripped...this might imply a bug in the SharpLiteModelBinder.)
- Although you have Email as a [DomainSignature], did you also intend to have a [NotNullNotEmpty] validator?  I.e., is it OK for a User to have an empty Email?

On a related note, there is a new Google Group discussion group for S#arp Lite at http://groups.google.com/group/sharp-lite

Comment: thanks for your help.  I post my question there with all the source code.  the email is tagged as [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")].  if something wrong with User, why when I enter an unique title, everything works,  User object still the same one as I enter a duplicate title.  I upload my entire application on github and repost my quesiton on sharp lite google group. http://groups.google.com/group/sharp-lite/browse_thread/thread/27cb231e48cd2b49